# Java Hashmaps word grouping won't return more than one ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

For a homework assignment I have to create a program that will cheat at hangman. In order to do this I need to come up with a way of grouping words into families via the words letter locations. So for instance if the word length is 4 and they guess "e" all words that go      "- - - e " will be in one of the hashmap's Arraylists with that pattern as a key and all the words that that go "- e - -" will be in another of the same hashmap's ArrayLists with the pattern as a key. My problem is that despite my program being able to identify the pattern. It still returns an empty set or one ArrayList containing all the words. I have been trying different things for over an hour now and I can't seem to get them to group correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code I have for the class that separates the words and adds them to the Hashmap.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class EvilEngine 
{
HashMap<StringBuilder, ArrayList> families = new HashMap<StringBuilder, ArrayList>();
int k = 0;
ArrayList<String> currentList = new ArrayList();
StringBuilder blankPattern = new StringBuilder("");
StringBuilder newPattern = new StringBuilder("");


public void PatternMatcher(ArrayList wordlist, char guess, Integer wordlength)
{

    String word;
    int j = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int biggest = 0;
    StringBuilder longest = null;    

    while(x < wordlist.size())
    {
        int i = 0;
        int index = 0;
        for (i=0; i < wordlength; i++)
        {
            blankPattern = blankPattern.append("-");
        }
        boolean boo = false;
        newPattern = blankPattern;
        word = (String) wordlist.get(x);
        index = word.indexOf(guess);
        while (index >= 0) 
        {
            blankPattern.setCharAt(index, guess);
            newPattern = blankPattern;
            index = word.indexOf(guess, index + 1);
        }
        this.PatternCompiler(word,newPattern);
        blankPattern = blankPattern.delete(0,wordlength);
        x++;
    }
}
public void PatternCompiler (String word, StringBuilder pattern)
{
        if(!families.containsKey(pattern))
        {
            ArrayList<String> newPatternList = new ArrayList();
            newPatternList.add(word);
            families.put(pattern, newPatternList);
        }
        if (families.containsKey(pattern))
        {
            ArrayList<String> oldPatternList = new ArrayList();
            oldPatternList = families.get(pattern);
            oldPatternList.add(word);
            families.put(pattern, oldPatternList);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

}
public HashMap<StringBuilder, ArrayList> returnFamilies (){
    return families;
}
}
```

Comment: Is every word in `wordlist` guaranteed to have length `wordlength`? You should maybe skip words with the wrong length.

Comment: Yes I already cut down the dictionary file into an ArrayList containing only words of the appropriate length. For some reason it keeps returning an empty map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are several more-or-less minor issues with your code, I suspect the main problem is that your `HashMap` has keys of type `StringBuilder` instead of `String`.  `HashMap` uses the [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) function of the key object to determine if it is already in the map or not.  For a `StringBuilder`, the hash value is probably just going to be the address of the object (using the implementation inherited from the `Object` class).

Since `newPattern` is a class-level variable whose scope is outside of the functions, when you pass it to the `PatternCompiler()` function, the parameter `pattern` there is just a *reference* to the *same* class-level object (i.e., will have the same hash code).  And this object (nor its hash code) never changes in your code because `blankPattern` is also declared at the class level and, while you change the *value* of `blankPattern`, you never change the object it refers to.  So re-assigning it to `newPattern` each time through your `while` loop does not change anything (and is basically clutter).

To fix that, you will want to make the key type of your `HashMap` be `String` instead of `StringBuilder`.  The `String` class defines a [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) function that will return different codes depending on the actual contents of the string (instead of just the address of the object like `StringBuilder`).  (Also, as indicated, there is no reason for `blankPattern` to be declared at the class level instead of just inside your `PatternMatcher()` function, and you don't need `newPattern` at all.)

While that was the main issue with your code, another pretty big issue has to do with the second `if` condition in your `PatternCompiler()` function.  In the previous `if` block you add a new ArrayList to families if there isn't already one for the pattern.  So no matter what, the second `if` conditional (`if (families.containsKey(pattern))`) will be true at that point.  Because both blocks add `word` to the list for `families`, there is the potential that some words will be added twice.

Good luck!

Comment: `StringBuilder` is not documented to implement `hashCode`, so it will use the default implementation of `Object`. *But please don't call that "the address of the object", because that's misleading and usually even wrong. Also, I'd add that using a mutable object as a key to a `Map` is an inherently dangerous operation (another reason to prefer `String`).

Comment: @Joachim_Saur Good point about mutable keys.  I guess my "probably" w.r.t. addresses above was too strong.  Having never really looked at how it's implemented myself, I'm wondering about the word "typically" as it is worded in the last paragraph of the hashCode() docs for Object that I linked to above, relative to your "usually wrong".  What is the normal implementation of this?  (Not trying to start a dispute -- I'm genuinely curious.)

Comment: AFAIK the OpenJDK (and the Sun JDK) calculates some hash of the initial address and stores it in the object header. There are alternative implementations in the source (including one that uses a randomizer), but they are disabled via compile-time switches. One main reason it's not the address alone is that the address can easily change when the garbage collector moves the object.